# parameters in python built-in functions min() and sorted()

Tags: python, function, sorting, min

I'm doing tasks on py.checkio.org, I have meet an exercise to write my own function `min()` and `max()`.

I have read documentation about this function in [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) and I'm surprised about described parameters, they look like:  `min(iterable, *[, key, default])`

I'm wondering what does this construction `*[,` mean, it is strange, because `*args` and `**kwargs` is clear, also `[,arg]` is clear.
But `*[,` is very strange, what does this parameter mean?

P.S [sorted() function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) has strange parameter asterisk: `sorted(... *, ...)` what can it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following applies to Python 3 (to which the OP linked).

---

The single star (`*`) in the function definition of [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) denotes that all following named parameters must be supplied as keyword arguments (*"keyword-only arguments"*, see [PEP 3102](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/)). That means the following won't work:

```
>>> sorted([1, 2, 3], lambda x: x)
[...]
TypeError: must use keyword argument for key function
```

Instead you *must* supply those parameters via keyword arguments:

```
>>> sorted([1, 2, 3], key=lambda x: x)
[1, 2, 3]
```

---

I'm not completely sure what the `, *[, key, default]` syntax shall denote (it's not valid Python but a documentation purpose) however I think the developers want to express the same thing, namely that you have to provide those parameters as keyword arguments (because `min` and `max` can take an arbitrary number of positional arguments that is the only way to do it).

Comment: @OP : this is the right answer of course. Edited mine.

Comment: thanks, i was searching the way how can i google this *, behavior, and got stucked. Thank you very much for explanation.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Yeah it has some neat features, definitely worth a look ;-)

Comment: @a_guest
@brunodesthuilliers, guys. do you know the URL, where can we found explanation about this `*` in python official documentation

Comment: @a_guest you should edit your answer to add the answer about the `[, key, default]` part meaning these are optional (and this case keyword only since they follow a `*`) args.

Comment: @СергейАстрейко It's [PEP 3102](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/) as linked in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The `[, key, default]` part is not Python syntax, it's general programming languages grammar syntax denoting optional parts (here optional arguments).

EDIT: the `*` part is explained in a_guest's answer (nb : this is for Python 3 only)